# Assigning a class name to column in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I get an error in my view, seemingly due to the `:class_name => "user"`
 clause in my model. Any ideas?

**Details**

I have a very simple self-referencing model in Rails. It is a friendship between 2 users.

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "user"
end
```

In my view, I get an error `uninitialized constant RoomidexRelationship::user`, which occurs when I add `<%= @friendship.friend.name %>` below.

```
<p>
  <%= @friendship.user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= @friendship.friend.name %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name should be in CamelCase

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```